Search for specific content in a file present in multiple sub folders - Linux
I have a 'feature_config.json' file which holds flag values for multiple features, something like this:
"feature1": {
     "enabled": true
}
"feature2": {
     "enabled": true
}

There is one main folder (folder1) which contains multiple subfolders (folder2, folder3, folder4, ...). Every subfolder has the file 'feature_config.json'. This is the sample folder structure:
folder1/folder2/feature_config.json
folder1/folder3/feature_config.json
folder1/folder4/feature_config.json
folder1/folder5/feature_config.json

The feature_config.json is present under all subfolders under the main folder (folder1).
The requirement is to return the names of the subfolders where the 'feature1' is enabled.
I tried grep with -r for searching under subfolders but it is only returning me the first subfolder where the 'feature1' is enabled instead of returning me all the subfolders where 'feature1' is enabled.
Thank you for all the help in advance.
